# when i maximizes my window my widgets are not replacing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to reposition the widgets when window maximized?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 100, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 81, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 160, 81, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 160, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use a layout instead of fixed geometries.

Comment: Kind of like what @RomhaKorev said but I will add stop using the Designer as it does not create pyqt friendly code and the coordinate system is just one of its many issues -- if you develop pyqt as it should be (using layouts) then it all functions like it ought to -- but if you choose to use that garbage code the Designer barfs out then you cannot expect all that much -- Note writing pyqt from scratch takes as much time (or less) than it does using the designer but you get 10 times better results.

Comment: @DennisJensen I take your point about the ugly formatting, but there is no *functional* difference between pyuic output and hand-written code.  Personally, I always exclude it from version control and linting, so I don't much care what it looks like. The biggest advantage of qt designer is that it makes experimentation *much* quicker and easier, since the preview facility can give you instant visual feedback. If the OP had spent a few minutes reading the [Quick Start Guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-quick-start.html#), they could have solved their problem easily (by using layouts).

Comment: @DennisJensen PS: what do you mean when you say "the coordinate system is just one of its many issues"?

Comment: @DennisJensen I agree with what ekhumoro points out, Qt Designer allows you to experiment and prototype the GUI flexibly, obviously if you do not know the tool then you could point out that it does not work. It helped me in my beginnings (and still helps) to understand how layouts work, how a widget behaves, etc.

Comment: Same here: I learnt how to hand-write layout code by reading pyuic output. Of course, such auto-generated code can be written more simply, but the ideas behind it are the same.

Comment: @ekhumoro -- yes I have stated that the Qt Designer should only be used for prototyping as that is the only thing it is actually useful for BUT I will again state if you learn how to code pyqt properly and retain code references you can create most windows just as fast or even faster than using the Designer further you have the added benefit of your prototype being able to be taken straight into production code

Comment: As to what I mean by one of its many issues -- is that as production code goes its garbage -- its horrible to have to troubleshoot -- its horrible to try to work with what it produces post creation -- pyqt is designed to use the layout system and it does not -- it seems to encourage beginners to use it which are the last folks that should be using it -- it encourages lazy minded coding something that seems to perpetuate itself in other areas of coding

Comment: Lastly I am sure I could come up with a few other issues that the Designer has if you really need more -- but the fact that it hurts beginners more than it helps them is to me its biggest down fall of all --- It should come with a major precautionary warning that it ought not to be used by beginners

Comment: @DennisJensen To say that "it encourages lazy minded coding" is something subjective. If you ask me: What do you want to invest time in: logic or prototyping? Well, for me in logic, and if you ask a designer, then you will surely answer in the prototyping. In production, the tools that allow the fastest project and that do not generate problems are used, so the use of Qt Designer in production is as correct as not using it.

Comment: Note I state that last part because Designer does not even attempt to use the layout system which is a MAJOR part of pyqt -- how can you create a tool that uses a layout system in creation but renders code that does not and then imply that the tool is some how pyqt friendly -- because by its basic nature it is not

Comment: @eyllanesc subjective it is not -- which takes more active thinking using a tool that you know creates bad code because it requires less thinking on the coders part about how to use the code properly to render the same image -- or actively creating the gui from scratch using the code properly

Comment: @DennisJensen Qt Designer does allow you to use layouts, it seems you don't know the tool, I recommend you check: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html

Comment: Yes @eyllanesc I have encountered that way of thinking numerous times and almost every time it is due to being called in to fix nightmare code that was created by someone cutting corners and having left of been let go and now the company has this heap of code that is anything but coder friendly that will take days to clean up and get working properly -- if the coder had not cut corners to begin with it might have taken a bit more time but they or anyone else could have easily worked with that code -- so NO it does not belong in production at all

Comment: I did not say it does not use layouts @eyllanesc -- I said it does use layouts but it does not produce code that uses layouts (or at least none that I have seen as of yet)  please quote me correctly

Comment: @DennisJensen No, a tool is to facilitate the development of a process. Already from there as the developer uses it is his own problem. The lazy thing is not an attitude that brings the tool to perse. Whether active or not is relative, you give more importance to writing thousands of lines of code and others give more importance to productivity. Each one with their tastes. Goodbye, I will not extend the discussion since it is not the right place here, if you want us to continue talking then create a chat and invite me :-) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197828/discussion-between-dennis-jensen-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @ekhumoro sure I have heard that saying -- but I do not blame my tools because I do not use bad tools such as the Desigtner -- I use quality tools for the purpose they were meant to be used for so that I can produce quality end products.  So considering that the Designer produces bad code that should not be used in production (and I could see that at a glance having had to deal with so much bad code in the past) why on earth would I waste time learning to use it when I can produce a window as quickly or quicker than using the Designer and have a 10 times better end product when done?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about layout management in PyQt5 here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/

Try as an option:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 100, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 81, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 160, 81, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 160, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        formLayout.addRow(self.label_2, self.lineEdit)
        formLayout.addRow(self.label_3, self.lineEdit_2)

        layoutV = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layoutV.addLayout(formLayout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you explain what your solution is about, a beginner will probably only use it without understanding the basis of the solution, and probably tomorrow make a new publication whose solution will be the same: layouts.